# sortable clones element instead of sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a sortable list with some tweaks here and there.

but recently, the list items get duplicated, when i try to sort them.
(everytime i pull one, another copy gets added).
I can't figure out why.

unfortunately, it doesn't run in  the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PSone/gttjc6q6/)

so here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    /**
     * determines if an item is to be removed from the list
     */
    var removeItem;
    $("#tracks").sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        connectWith: "li",
        placeholder: "sort_placeholder",
        helper: "clone",
        distance: 20,
        sort: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            updatePlaylist();
        },
        over: function (event,ui) {
            updatePlaylist();
            removeItem = false;
            //gets the class of the original item to add to the clipinfo-field
            var originalClass = ui.helper.context.childNodes[0].className;
            var small_slot = originalClass.match(/(\d+)/g)[0];
            var small_clip = originalClass.match(/(\d+)/g)[1];
            // shows the original index in the playlist
            ui.item.context.children[0].innerHTML = small_clip;
            ui.item.context.children[0].classList.add("slot_clip_info");
        },
        out: function () {
            updatePlaylist();
            // if an item is pulled out of the list, it gets marked for deletion
            removeItem = true;
        },
        beforeStop: function(event,ui) {
            // if an item has been pulled out of the list, remove it
            if (removeItem) {
                ui.item.remove();
            }
        },
        stop: function(event,ui) {

            var list = $('#tracks');
            var count = list.children(':not(.placeholder)').length;
            list.children('.placeholder').css("display", count > 0 ? "none" : "block");
            list.children(':not(.placeholder)').each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass().attr('style', '');  // removes the automatically added styles (width etc)
                $(this).addClass("ui-state-default pl_clipEntry");
            })

            // after every update, save the playlist

            savePlaylist();
        }
    });
});


function updatePlaylist () {
var list = $("#tracks");
var count = list.children(':not(.placeholder)').length;
list.children('.placeholder').css("display", count > 0 ? "none" : "block");

list.children(':not(.placeholder)').each(function(index,elem) {
    var button = $(elem).children().eq(1).children().eq(0);
    $(button).attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
    $(button).click(function(){emitCommand('playlist_clip ' + index);});
})
}
```

and the draggable where the items come from:

```
$(function() {
        $(".pl_clipEntry").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            revert: "invalid",
            connectToSortable: "#tracks",
            distance: 20,
            helper: function(){
                return $(this).clone().width($('#placeholder').width());   // for the drag-clone to keep the correct width
            },
            stop: function(ui, event) {
                $($(ui).children("li")[0]).addClass(".slot_clip_info");
             },
            zIndex: 100
        });
    });
```

is there a way to determine if an item originates from the sortable itself?
i want items to be added, if i pull them in from outside, but not if i reorder them inside the list

UPDATE:
(maybe) important info:
the FIRST sort works.
every sort after that copies the item

thanks :)

SOLUTION:

i had a setInterval set to reload the playlist every 5 seconds.
that explains everything:
the first one or two sorts work just fine, then the list gets reloaded, and when i sort then, the items are consideres "from outside" and added.
i removed the interval and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `helper: "clone"` option, and everything will be fine :) This helper clones an item.

Comment: didn't work... or better: it SEEMED to work, but then the cloning reappeared :/... can this be caused by something external? something completely elsewhere in the code?

Comment: And to make it work on fiddle you just have to add a jQuery UI library (External Resources tab on Fiddle)

Comment: stupid me (or smart me? :D ) i just found it out myself. and it was indeed a completely different place in the code, gonne update the question. thanks :)

Comment: Congrats :) And I also have found an error on `var originalClass = ui.helper.context.childNodes[0].className;` - console on fiddle says `originalClass` is null (maybe it's only on fiddle), so I fixed it: `var originalClass = $($(ui.helper.context).children('span')[0]).attr('class');`